# Image not going as a body of email but some random lines are coming

Tags: python

I have written a script that sends image as the body of the email. But instead of image, random lines are coming. This is my script:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage


msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('related')
msgRoot['Subject'] = 'test message'
msgRoot['From'] = strFrom
msgRoot['To'] = strTo
msgRoot.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'

msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msgRoot.attach(msgAlternative)

msgText = MIMEText('This is the alternative plain text message.')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText)


msgText = MIMEText('<b>Some <i>HTML</i> text</b> and an image.<br><img src="cid:image1"><br>Nifty!', 'html')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText)


fp = open('test.jpg', 'rb')
msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()

msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
msgRoot.attach(msgImage)


import smtplib

server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
port = 587

sender = 'mysender@gmail.com'
recipient = 'myreceiver@gmail.com'
subject = 'Gmail SMTP Test'
body = 'blah blah blah'

"Sends an e-mail to the specified recipient."

body = "" + body + "" + msgImage.as_string()

#This is where I have attached the image in body. 

headers = ["From: " + sender,
           "Subject: " + subject,
           "To: " + recipient,
           "MIME-Version: 1.0",
           "Content-Type: text/html"]
headers = "\r\n".join(headers)

session = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)

session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.ehlo
session.login(sender, 'mypassword')

session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
session.quit()
```

This is what I receive on mail :

blah blah blahContent-Type: image/jpeg MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-ID: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QBaRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABQMBAAUAAAABAAAASgMDAAEA AAABAAAAAFEQAAEAAAABAQAAAFERAAQAAAABAAAOw1ESAAQAAAABAAAOwwAAAAAAAYagAACxj//b AEMAAgEBAgEBAgICAgICAgIDBQMDAwMDBgQEAwUHBgcHBwYHBwgJCwkICAoIBwcKDQoKCwwMDAwH CQ4PDQwOCwwMDP/bAEMBAgICAwMDBgMDBgwIBwgMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwM DAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDP/AABEIAl0DjQMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAfAAABBQEBAQEBAQAA AAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EAACAQMDAgQDBQUEBAAAAX0BAgMABBEFEiExQQYTUWEHInEU MoGRoQgjQrHBFVLR8CQzYnKCCQoWFxgZGiUmJygpKjQ1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2Rl ZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK 0tPU1dbX2Nna4eLj5OXm5+jp6vHy8/T19vf4+fr/xAAfAQADAQEBAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUG BwgJCgv/

.......  (many lines)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Just in, if someone can tell me some way so that I can send the image as attachment, then also it will be helpful to me.

Comment: Those are not "random", that's your image in base64 encoding.  Without proper formatting, it's hard to tell, but superficially, the snippet you posted looks correct.

Comment: So how can I see the image in actual format?

Comment: If it is correctly encoded, any graphical mail client should be able to show it.  If it is not, you need to add more information to your question; maybe the text of a complete (hopefully very short) message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are createing two messages: one with the embedded image and one with the internal representation of the image, and then you send the last. This is why you only get that 'gibberish'.

To clarify, you are setting two times the `subject`, `from` and `to` elements of the e-mail header, attaching the body HTML and the image to the first and the `image.as_string()` to the second. Then you proceed to send the second, containing

> blah blah blah[String representation of the image]

I don't really know why do you do the work two times, but if you (as I presume) only want to send one message with a picture, you should remove the second message and send only the first one (`msgRoot.as_string()` instead of `headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body`). Your posted code then would be something like this:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
import smtplib

server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
port = 587
sender = 'mysender@gmail.com'
recipient = 'myreceiver@gmail.com'


# Create message and set message fields
msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('related')
msgRoot['Subject'] = 'test message'
msgRoot['From'] = strFrom
msgRoot['To'] = strTo
msgRoot.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'

msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msgRoot.attach(msgAlternative)

msgText = MIMEText('This is the alternative plain text message.')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText)

# Actual message body (with the image in the HTML code)
msgText = MIMEText('<b>Some <i>HTML</i> text</b> and an image.<br><img src="cid:image1"><br>Nifty!', 'html')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText)

# Open image and read it
fp = open('test.jpg', 'rb')
msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()

# Attach image to 'image1' in the e-mail
msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
msgRoot.attach(msgImage)


# Send message
session = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)
session.starttls()
session.login(sender, 'mypassword')

session.sendmail(sender, recipient, msgRoot.as_string())
session.quit()
```

Edit: If you remove `session.ehlo()` it also works. But to be honest, I don't know if it's needed or not.

Comment: Excellent !! I can't thank you in words. You have solved one of my current urgent problem. Thanksss.